# Making 'persistent' ArcMap tool without creating Python add-in?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, geoprocessing, arctoolbox, python-addin

I want to make an addon that, while editing in ArcMap, will track where I pan and move the viewport. I have the pieces together, but I don't like debugging with the Python Add-In wizard, because I have to recompile and restart ArcMap each time I modify the code.

Is there another way to create this type of 'persistent' script without using an add-in? If I make a toolbox tool and run it, will it run in the background, and how would I stop it? All the toolbox tools I've ever created have a certain task they perform and, once completed, the tool stops running. Same with ModelBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

I've personally had little experience in using a *Python* AddIn as I would have approached this problem using ArcObjects and VB .Net. You specifically mention editing and not liking debugging in Python. You could create an extension that would listen out for the starting and stopping of an edition session. Once started it could log the tracking of your movement. Key ArcObject Interfaces would be [IEditor3](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0020000000r0000000) and [IEditEvents](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/IEditEvents_Interface/00200000009s000000/).